# A Bug in Character "l" (such as "like") in Cosmos Graph

Tags: c#, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I have run the following query in cosmos graph (in C#):

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = db.Client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(db.Graph, $"g.addV().property('value','{HttpUtility.UrlEncode("\"like\"")}')");
var result = query.ExecuteNextAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

As you can see "l" in "like" is in lowercase. However, when I see the result in Azure portal "Like" is stored! The question is *where does this problem come from?*. Be aware that, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` exists because in cosmos db there are some problem in storing some specific characters such as `'` (Although there is not any of these characters here, but in real case I have).
Anyhow, the problem does not come from `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, because its result is watched and it was "%22like%22".

As I have tested, this problem happens for "l" character not for "b" as an instance. See the output in Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: You do realize that there's simply no way that `L` is handled differently.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Plausibly yes. But, what happened for this query? This is a reproducible bug. You can try.

Comment: What is the *actual* string that you store? Store and inspect it before you interpolate it. What is the result of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` ? BTW, why HttpUtility.UrlEncode instead of Uri.EscapeUriString? Not that it matters, the result should be the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem does not come from `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, because its result is watched and it was "%22like%22". Anyhow, it is not matter what is the real string. The problem can be producible by the above simple query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some known bugs right now in the Gremlin parser where certain keywords that have meaning in the SQL syntax aren't being handled properly. Strange behavior can also be observed with the value `all`. We've spoken directly to the Cosmos team about this and a fix to the parser is supposed to be coming soon.

Comment: Sometimes, when you hear hoofbeats, it *is* zebras instead of horses

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a bug and was resolved in [Microsoft.Azure.Graphs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graphs) package version >= `0.3.0-preview`.

Please upgrade your nuget package reference if you have not already.